# Parse.com : Fetch all users with no role assigned

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, user-management

I have some users in which some of the users have `administrator` role assigned to them. All other users doesn't have a role assigned to them.

I am able to fetch only users who have `administrator` role assigned to them using the following code.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
query.equalTo("name", "administrator");
query.first({
    success : function(role) {
        var relation = role.getUsers();
        relation.query().find({
            success : function(results) {
                console.log(results);
            },
            error : function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    },
    error : function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

How can I fetch users to whom any role is not assigned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Parse.Query.notEqualTo`:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
query.notEqualTo("name", "administrator");
query.first({
    success : function(role) {
        var relation = role.getUsers();
        relation.query().find({
            success : function(results) {
                console.log(results);
            },
            error : function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    },
    error : function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Also, maybe these filters may help you

```
query.doesNotExist("name");
query.notContainedIn("role", ["Administrator"]);
```

https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-query-constraints

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But all other users (not administrators) doesn't have a role assigned to them. Basically I have only one role administrator. Will this work in that case?

Comment: Can you give us an input sample to see the document structure?